# Lookahead assertion with dot

Tags: python, regex

I need to remove trailing zeros from string represents floating point value `x.xx`

I try to use `re.sub` but no effect

```
re.sub("(?=\.[0-9])0", "", "1.23, 2.50, 2.00, 2.30, 5.03")
```

*UPDATE*

In my particular case there are only two digits after the dot. And I need to remove both zeros. With **Ashwini Chaudhary** and **Porges** help currently I use `\.00|(?<=\.[0-9])0` probably better one expression exists. Remove zeros before point is not my goal.

Also would be interesting for me to see some general solution for various number of zeros not only for two.

Comment: Will there always be exactly two digits after the dot?  If both digits are zero, do you want to retain the first one, or get rid of the dot?  (That is, should `2.00` become `2.0` or just `2`?)  Will there always be at least one digit *before* the dot? (That is, could we expect to see a number like `.12`, or would it always appear as `0.12`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use lookbehind assertion not lookahead:

```
>>> re.sub("(?<=\.[0-9])0", "", "1.23, 2.50, 2.00, 2.30, 5.03")
'1.23, 2.5, 2.0, 2.3, 5.03'
```

---

```
(?<=\.[0-9])0
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JOSIhSNu2YI47Cjc)

Comment: debuggex.com is awesome

Answer (score 3):

You want lookbehind, not lookahead. In your current expression `\.[0-9]` is trying to match at the same time as the `0`, which will never happen.

Try: `"(?<=\.[0-9])0"`